# Is every bounded Holomorphic function on C\{1} and C\{0} constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe that since they are bounded then we will have a bounded entire function which has to be constant by liouville's. Any help or clarification would be great.

Comment: Holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ and bounded implies that at $1$ it has a removable singularity. Therefore, it is really entire, and bounded.

Comment: exactly and thus by liouvilles it has to be constant. Is this the same then for C\{0}? @conditionalMethod

Comment: The only important thing above about $\{1\}$ is that it was a point.